# Change URL in link after code has been output

Tags: javascript, html, dotnetnuke

So, I have a dotNetNuke site that was developed by someone else. These developers are not available to respond to requests as fast as I need in this case, and I have to fix something on a customer's site ASAP.

Somehow, the Home link in the site's side nav is pointing to the Contact Us page. Not sure how this was done, but I have limited access to the backend of the site (what's there is a mess anyway).

I'm looking for a way to change the URL of the Home nav item only from http://www.mywebsite.com/subdir/ContactUs/tabid/2530/Default.aspx to http://www.mywebsite.com/subdir/. I've tried swapping out the text with JavaScript to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lostPixelx suggest and seeing it kind have some hack that DotNetNuke do to the the link work. Please add the following to a javascript

```
  $(function() {
    $('#tddnn_dnnMENU_ctldnnMENU2529').click(function(){self.location="http://www.mydomain.com/subdir/"})
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was hacking at the script lostPixels posted but still couldn't get it. And after posting your script into the content editor I can't get this to work either.

Comment: I have edited the answer.

It will overlap any action withing the TD and directly goes to the require page

Answer (score 0):

Running this Jquery code will remedy your issue... but it seems like your site has some issues that you should address, not bandage with JS.

```
$('h1.logo a').attr('href','http://www.mydomain.com/subdir/');
```

Comment: The site is being re-built with a different system. Right now all I need is a bandage. I think that is going to change the link on the top left logo. Where I need to change it is on the Home link on the side nav.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you go in to the PAGE SETTINGS for the HOME page via the Admin/Pages (page management).

From there, on the last "tab" in the settings, towards the bottom, you can find a "URL" or "Navigation" Section, make sure nothing is selected there, then save the page settings.

Comment: Like I said, I have limited access to the backend, which is a mess. That is the first thing I would have tried, not some jQuery hack.

Comment: You don't have "Admin" access to the site?

Comment: I do to a certain extent, but like I said, the site is a mess and the backend is convoluted. Anyway, my problem was solved.

Comment: My way is the better way the solve the problem, in terms of doing things the right way in DotNetNuke, I highly recommend doing it that way instead of with a jquery hack

Comment: Yes, I know that. Seriously, I DO NOT have the access to do it that way or I would have done it. I cannot do it via the admin panel. I don't know how else to explain it to you. I came here for help BECAUSE I CAN'T DO IT THE WAY IT SHOULD BE DONE. What are you not getting? It doesn't matter how many times you tell me that is the "right way" to do it, I can't do it that way.

Comment: To be fair, you never said you don't have access to that admin page until your comment in which you went off. Prior to that you said "to a certain extent"